# NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust is ssl

Tags: ios, ipad, nsurlconnection

I have trouble understanding NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust. In my App I have to use both http and https connections based on the server. My questions is If I get a NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust challenge will it be a safe assumption to take is as https connection. What exactly should I respond to this challenge.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether receiving `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` always indicates an https connection. I don't see why or how a plain http connection could cause an `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` authentication challenge so I'd assume it's https but I don't know for certain.
But the `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` has an `NSURLProtectionSpace`, which in turn has a property [`receivesCredentialSecurely`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtectionSpace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLProtectionSpace/receivesCredentialSecurely). The documentation is a bit unspecific, but I'd assume that this property indicates a secure connection to the server which in the http/https case would mean it's https.

Regarding what to respond, there is a helpful thread on the macnetworkprog-mailinglist regarding this topic: [Question](https://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2012/Jul/msg00011.html) + [Answer](https://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2012/Jul/msg00012.html)

Summary: The `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` is not about you, the client, responding to an authentication challenge of the server but instead giving you, the client, the opportunity to check whether you should even trust the server at all. In that case the `protectionSpace` of the challenge contains a `serverTrust` object/struct that contains all the information needed to validate whether this server should be trusted. Generally, you would use the `SecTrustEvaluate` function to check the `serverTrust` and act according to the result of that check. You can find more information here: [Overriding TLS Chain Validation Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012544)

If the check determines that the server should be trusted you [create an `NSURLCredential` with the `serverTrust` object](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredential_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLCredential/credentialForTrust:) and pass that to the authentication challenge sender/completion block.

You can find a quite extensive example project by Apple here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html
It's quite old (iOS 3/4, pre-Arc) and only dealing with the old `NSURLConnectionDelegate` which had to delegate methods instead of one (like the new one and `NSURLSessionDelegate`). But the verification shown there and the different scenarios that you could implement still apply and should be easily transferable to `NSURLSession`.